# Rails 3.2.x double request in ajax and non-ajax forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

When I start my app in production environment all my forms make a double request to the server even if they don't have the `:remote => true`. Until know everything I have found about this matter is related with the asset pipeline included since Rails 3.1 and the issue is that some files in the assets are duplicating something but I think is not my case because it also happends in the normal forms (no ajax).

For webserver the application uses is Thin with default configuration,

Here are my requires for the manifest of application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.cycle.all
//= require jquery.alphanumeric
//= require jquery.pageless
//= require jquery.ui.min.js
//= require jquery.fastLiveFilter.js
//= require_tree .
```

non of this files are duplicated in the differents path that require_tree searchs.

This is my production.rb

```
Web::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Amazon SES
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses
end
```

Here is my application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

#require 'rails/all'

#require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Web
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
    #config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib", "#{config.root}/lib/**/"]

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Commented because we don't use AR nor DB
    #config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```